# Java Jackson Views

Tags: java, jackson

Все добрый вечер,
можно ли использовать `BaseViews.Reduced` для фильтрации и *BaseViews.Reduced* и 
 *ExtendedBaseViews.Reduced*? Судя по тесту, то нет. Но может быть я что-то делаю не так.

```java
class BaseViews {
    public static class Reduced {}
}

...

class ExtendedBaseViews  {
    public static class Reduced extends BaseViews.Reduced {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу на свой вопрос. Да, можно так делать. Но работает только с интерфейсами. Причину такого поведения в документации к Jackson не нашел.